# having issue with referral system laravel

Tags: laravel

so i was trying to build a basic referral system where new registered can input there referral username and the referral count will increase and also the referral table will be populated with the referral id and newly user id
i am not getting or doing it right need help

```
public function register()
    {

        $user = User::create([
            // 'name' => $this->name,
            'username' => $this->username,
            'email' => $this->email,
            'password' => encrypt($this->password)
        ]);

        if ($user = User::where('username', $this->referral)->first()) {
             $user->increment('referrel_count');
            $user = Referral::create([
                'user_id' => auth()->id,
                'referred_by_id' => $user->id,

            ]);

        }
        $user->notify(new WelcomeUser($user));
        Auth::login($user);
        return redirect(route('profile.show', auth()->user()->username));

    }
```

table

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('referrals', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignId('user_id');
            $table->string('referred_by_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

model user

```
 public function referral()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Referral::class);
    }
```

referral model

```
 public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }
```

Comment: What isn't working for you? Do you get any errors? What version of Laravel are you using? What makes you think you're not doing it right?

Comment: The problem is most likely that you are overriding your user variable with the referrer. `$user = Referral::create....` - but as @steven7mwesigwa mentioned, please include a reasonable amount of information.